# How to import multiple matrices from a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, import

I'm looking for a way to import `N` matrices from one file to a single 3D array. I know the number of rows `m` and the number of columns `n` of each matrix (respectively listed in two lists `m[N]` and `n[N]`).

For example I have `N=3` matrices like these:

```
1  2   3   4
5  6   7   8
9  10  11  12
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
10  11  12
1  2  3  4   5   6 
7  8  9  10  11  12
```

They are matrices of dimension `3x4`, `4x3`, `2x6` respectively, so in this case `m = [3,4,2]` and `n = [4,3,6]`.
I would store them in an object of the type `M[i][j][k]` where `i,j,k` are the indeces that identify the matrix, the row and the column respectively (in this case `M[1][2][0]=7`).

For example in C++ this can be easily done:

```
ifstream file ("filename.txt");
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < m[i]; j++)
      for(int k = 0; k < n[i]; k++)
        file >> M[i][j][k];

file.close();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked `numpy` or `nested python list`?

Comment: can you show `M`?

Comment: @Epsi95, I usually use numpy.genfromtxt but here the problem is the different number of columns. Nested python list could be the right way, but i don't know how to import the data.

Comment: @python_user for the above example M[1][2][0] would give 7

Comment: "I know the number of rows m and the number of columns n of each matrix." how do you have these m and n?

Comment: @python_user from previous analysis. The file i want to import, was created by me in this way because it is easy to read in C++, but not in Python. `m` and `n` are 2 lists of lenght N.

Comment: edit m and n to the question, you need a MCVE, for which m and n are needed

Comment: `m = [3, 4, 2]; n = [4, 3 6]` @Wil ?

Comment: Edited just few seconds ago. Hope it is clearer. Thank you @python_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `itertools.islice` to get what you want. `islice` allows you to read lines from the file without having to read the whole file into the memory.

```
from itertools import islice

m = [3, 4, 2]
n = [4, 3, 6]

M = []

with open('matrix_data.txt') as file:
    for row_count in m:
        rows = islice(file, row_count) # read `row_count` lines from the file
        rows = [row.split() for row in rows] # split every line in the file on whitespace
        rows = [[int(cell) for cell in row] for row in rows] # convert to int
        M.append(rows) # add to `M`

for matrix in M:
    print(matrix)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! So the n[N] is not needed.

Comment: not for the way I suggested, `m` is enough, you can upvote the answer as well :) if it helped

Comment: how can I convert M to a np.ndarray? thank you

Comment: you mean a 3d numpy array?

Comment: Exactly! Because in this way, for example the first row of the first matrix `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is a list.

Comment: idk `numpy` a lot but I guess `np.asarray(M)` should work?